# Reference a single column from one table 2 times to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, associations

I have two tables:

1. users
2. posts

A post belongs to a user and a post can be awarded to another user. How can I map this association in rails models?

These are my current associations, which are not working:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_one :awarded_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'awarded_to_user_id'
```

When I try to access `post.awarded_user`, I get this error in rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.awarded_to_user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`awarded_to_user_id` = 8 LIMIT 1
```

The query searches for `user.awarded_to_user_id` however, I need it to search in `posts` to become `posts.awarded_to_user_id`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please see if [any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brails%5D+two+associations+to+same+model) help.  If they do, please click on "close" to tell the system that this question is a duplicate of the one that helped.

Comment: @WayneConrad no, they do not help. They all use the same `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` from the assigned `:class_name`. What I want is that the `:class_name` should be the same but the `:foreign_key` should be not from the assigned `:class_name` but from `posts` model.

Comment: Conceptually, the foreign key `awarded_to_user_id` must be in users table because it is the user who `belongs_to`, and a post `has_one`. For what you are saying, you have to revert the scenario: `Post belongs_to :awarded_user`, and `User has_one :awarded_post`

Comment: @ArslanAli can you please post an answer with the code? It's really to complex for me as a beginner to understand this. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, generate a migration that adds a column into posts table.

```
class AddAwardedToUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration                   
  def change                                                                
    add_column :posts, :awarded_to_user_id, :integer, index: true
  end                                                                      
end
```

And now, in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base                                             
  has_many :posts                                
  has_one :awarded_post, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: 'awarded_to_user_id'  
end
```

And for `Post`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base                                             
  belongs_to :awarded_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'awarded_to_user_id'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And now, in this case, you can achieve what you are saying:

```
user_zaid = User.create first_name: "Zaid"
user_ali = User.create first_name: "Ali"

post = Post.create description: "A less descriptive post"

post.user = user_zaid
post.awarded_user = user_ali

post.save


# Or the other way

user_ali.posts << post # Since, user has_many posts.
user_ali.awarded_post = post # Since, user has_one awarded_post. 

user_ali.save

# How to fetch:

User.last.posts # it will give you the posts.
User.last.awarded_post # it will give you the (single) awarded post.
```

And for `Post`,

```
Post.last.user # it will give you the user which it belongs to
Post.last.awarded_user # it will give you the user which it was **awarded** to
```